Unable to connect to kafka in different container
I am trying to connect kafka and express backend residing in different containers

NOTE: I have already refered to some stackoverflow solutions and tried to implement it but it didnt work

express.ts

async function connectToKafka() {
    try {
        const kafka = new kafkajs.Kafka({
            clientId: KAFKA_CLIENT_ID,
            brokers: ['kafka:9092','kafka:29092'],
        });
        producer = kafka.producer();
        await producer.connect();
        console.log('Connected to Kafka');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to Kafka:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}


docker-compose.yml
services:
  kafka:
    image: apache/kafka
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/dockerdata
      - ./server.properties:/etc/kafka/server.properties # loads properties I have shown below
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - app-network

  # express backend recieves request and stores temp data or publishes to kafka
  express:
    build: ./express
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network

I know for sure both containers are running perfectly after running docker compose up --build
very interestingly I noticed this
express-1         | {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-08-21T02:46:16.151Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"express-producer","stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)"}

I have passed broker as kafka:9092 and it tries to hit localhost:9092 instead.
I thought this was a configuration error (with advertised listeners) while starting Kafka so I tried this but It still does the same thing
server.properties
broker.id=0
log.dirs=/kafka/data
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:29092
kafka.inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092

I have been learning kafka and docker and stuck here for some time now not sure what am I missing

You are literally telling kafka to redirect clients to localhost:9092 in your server.properties.


Your code only needs one address for one broker, not two different ports 2) I doubt your broker is even starting. Zookeeper isn't running, so what's zookeeper.connect pointing to. Plus, listeners should use 0.0.0.0 address to allow external connections. 3) You might want to look at the native image rather than using no image tag

